# "I happen to be free now" or "I have happened to be free now" when talking about a present situation?

Tags: present-perfect, present-simple

Do I say *I happen to be free now* or *I have happened to be free now* meaning that the circumstances are such that I am free at the moment? For example:

> I told you I was going to be busy, but **I happen to** be free at the moment.
>
> I told you I was going to be busy, but **I have happened to** be free at the moment.

Comment: "At the moment" – present tense, so the first one.

Comment: "I have happened to be free at the moment" sounds very strange. The word "told", without an object (the person being told) is also strange - it's "I told them [or you, etc[ I was going to be busy", but otherwise it's "I said I was going to be busy".

Comment: What makes you think that it's okay to use the perfect past right next to 'at the moment'?